# Find the unbiased estimator for the parameter $\sigma$.

Tags: probability, statistics, estimation

**TASK**: Let $(X_1, X_2)$ is a random i.i.d. sample from $N(0, \sigma ^2)$ distribution. Find the unbiased estimator for the parameter $\sigma$.

**SOLUTION**: The estimator $\theta$ is unbiased if $E\theta = \theta$.
In this case $\theta = \sigma ^2$, and $\sigma^2 = \frac{1}{2}( X_1^2 + X_2^2$).

So $E\sigma^2 = E\frac{1}{2}(X_1^2+X_2^2) = \frac{1}{2}(EX_1^2 + EX_2^2)$

$EX_i^2 = VarX_i + (EX_i^2) = VarX_i + 0 = \sigma^2$

And $E\sigma^2 =  \sigma^2$ so this estimator is unbiased.

**QUESTION** That's it?. I don't understand how we choose $\sigma^2$ Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that you should recognize the formula for sample variance, $s^2$, and use the guess that the sample variance is an unbiased estimator of the population variance, $\sigma^2$.

First thing to note: it's more appropriate to use different letters for the estimator versus the thing we are trying to estimate--here I'm using $s$ for the estimator and $\sigma$ for the population parameter we are trying to estimate.

I'm hypothesizing that the sample variance $s^2 = \frac{1}{2}(X_1^2 + X_2^2)$ is an unbiased of the population variance $\sigma^2$. A few facts we will use:

1. We know that $Var(X_1) = Var(X_2) = \sigma^2$, since they are from the same population.
2. We know that the variance formula is $Var(X_1) = E(X_1^2) + E(X_1)^2 = E(X_1^2)$ since $E(X_1) = 0$. It's similar to show that $Var(X_2) = E(X_2^2)$.

Then, using all the information I prove unbiasedness.

$$
\begin{align*}
E(s^2) &= E\left(\frac{1}{2}(X_1^2 + X_2^2)\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{2}(E(X_1^2) + E(X_2^2)) \\
&= \frac{1}{2}(Var(X_1) + Var(X_2)) \\
&= \frac{1}{2}(\sigma^2 + \sigma^2) \\
&= \frac{1}{2}(2 \sigma^2) \\
&= \sigma^2
\end{align*}
$$

Since we showed the expected value of our estimator, $E(s^2)$, is equal to the population parameter we are trying to estimate, $\sigma^2$, we have proved unbiasedness.

Comment: Thank you so much! But I'm a little confusing because the answer is $|X_1-X_2| \frac{\sqrt(\pi)}{2}$ And I don't understand what does it mean.

Comment: Lopirony: Pavan provided an estimator of $\sigma^2$ but you asked for an unbiased estimator of $\sigma$. The first thing to do is figure out how to obtain a reasonable estimate of $\sigma$. It's  not clear to me how they obtained the answer you provided.

Comment: Can we say what Pavan did is enough because of as $\sigma^2 = Es^2$ we have $\sigma = \sqrt{Es^2} = \sigma$?